# find first element and index matching condition in list

Tags: python, list

Consider this simple example

```
mylist = [-1,-2,3,4,5,6]

for idx, el in enumerate(mylist):
    if el > 0:
        myidx, myel = idx, el
        break

myidx, myel
Out[20]: (2, 3)
```

I am interested in finding the first index and the corresponding first element in a python list that matches a specific condition (here, this is simply > 0).

In the code above, I loop over the elements using `enumerate` and then use the if clause to find the correct elements. This looks very cumbersome to me. Is there a better way to do this? Using a native python function for instance?

Thanks!

Comment: The approach described in the question (imperative for-loop) has a clear advantage of breaking the iteration as soon as the condition is met and doesn't require intermediary data structures in memory. The list-comprehension versions in the answers below will almost invariably run through the whole list, before checking for the condition and require one or more intermediary data structures (new lists of equal length) in memory. For small lists, nothing of these matters, but for big ones could be very important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it in a list comprehension. This is basically the same as your code but condensed into one line, and it builds a list of results that match the criteria.

The first way gets all the matches

```
mylist = [-1,-2,3,4,5,6]

results = [(i, el) for i, el in enumerate(mylist) if el > 0]
```

Another way would be to use a generator expression which is probably faster, and just unpack it. This gets the first one.

```
*next((i, el) for i, el in enumerate(mylist) if el > 0))
```

This loops the list and checks the condition, then puts the index and element into a tuple. Doing this inside parentheses turns it into a generator, which is much faster because it hasn't actually got to hold everything in memory, it just generates the responses as you need them. Using `next()` you can iterate through them. As we only use next() once here it just generates the first match. Then we unpack it with `*`

As there are two other valid answers here I decided to use timeit module to time each of them and post the results. For clarity I also timed the OP's method. Here is what I found:

```
import timeit
# Method 1 Generator Expression
print(timeit.timeit('next((i, el) for i, el in enumerate([-1,-2,3,4,5,6]) if el > 0)', number=100000))
0.007089499999999999

# Method 2 Getting index of True
print(timeit.timeit('list(x > 0 for x in [-1,-2,3,4,5,6]).index(True)', number=100000))
0.008104599999999997

# Method 3 filter and lambda
print(timeit.timeit('myidx , myel = list(filter(lambda el: el[1] > 0, enumerate([-1,-2,3,4,5,6])))[0]', number=100000))
0.0155314

statement = """
for idx, el in enumerate([-1,-2,3,4,5,6]):
    if el > 0:
        myidx, myel = idx, el
        break
"""

print(timeit.timeit(statement, number=100000))
0.04074070000000002
```

Comment: nice but what about multiple matchings?

Comment: This should find all elements `> 0` and return a list of tuples containing the index and the element. I've not actually run it.

Comment: Ah wait I just ran it an I'm comparing the index. I'll edit now so it outputs the same as yours

Comment: Yeah I didn't realise you only wanted one result. The generator expression is the best way in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```py
l = [-1,-2,3,4,5,6]
list(x > 0 for x in l).index(True)
# Output: 2
```

To find all patters, we can use python built in functions using

```py
from itertools import filterfalse
f = filterfalse(lambda x: x[1] <= 0, enumerate(l))
print(list(f))
# [(2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3)]
```

Comment: interesting but I dont understand what is going on here. isnt the list returning a boolean of True False?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ It goes through the elements one by one and check the clause `x > 0`. So the list converts to `[False, False, True, .....]`. Then `index()` find the first `True` element in the list

Comment: ah yes, but I am interested in both the index and the element!

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ It is doable using Python built in `filterfalse`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the combination of `lambda` and `filter` like this:

```
mylist = [-1,-2,3,4,5,6]

myidx, myel = list(filter(lambda el: el[1] > 0, enumerate(mylist)))[0]
print("({}, {})".format(myidx, myel))
```

Explanation:

The `filter()` function which offers an elegant way to filter out all the elements takes in a function and a list as arguments. Here they are `lambda` and `mylist`. Since you want to get the corresponding index, we need to use `enumerate` to wrap up `enumerate(mylist)`.

Basically, `enumerate(mylist)` returns a tuple of an index and the corresponding value. Our condition here is the comparison between the value and `0` so that's why we get `el[1]` instead of `el[0]` to compare with `0`.

The results will be casted to `list`. This list includes all the pairs `(index, value)` that meet our condition. Here we want to get the first pair so that's why we have `[0]` at the end.

Output:

```
(2, 3)
```

Comment: interesting, thanks! can you explain a bit more the logic here?

Comment: I updated my answer adding the explanation.

Comment: This approach has the disadvantage of iterating the whole list, even if the result could have been already found in earlier elements.